# Local Analysis from SonarQube Plugin (Eclipse) is very slow

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I have on SonarQube Server 5.1 a project configured. This project has ~4k files and ~1.4 millions of lines of code.

I configured a Java Profile with about 600 rules (SonarQube, PMD, FindBugs..)
In my Eclipse, I installed a configured the Plugin of SonarQube version 3.4.

However, when I execute the SonarQube Analysis, the analysis takes about 20 minutes.

Is that time is fair for this project's size? How can I improve the time spent on the analysis?

[Logs from execution by maven in the command line](http://pastebin.com/j0paWQnM)

Command used: `mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.inclusions=**/TesteBO.java`

Comment: What version of the Eclipse plugin are you using? Normally, only the files that have been changed (compared to the reference on the SQ server) should be analyzed, so it shouldn't take that much time. Can you please put on pastebin.com the log of the SQ analysis that is displayed in the Console view?

Comment: I'm using Plugin SonarQube version 3.4. The default type analysis of this version is Incremental, but its toke too much time to make the analysis.

Comment: Please, post your logs somewhere. Without them, we can't help you.

Comment: When i run the Sonar plugin on Eclipse, did not generate log. How can i get the log from plugin?

Comment: Hi Fabrice!
I added the logs from execution in command line. This execution spend 50 minutes.
When i execute from sonar plugin, spends ~15 minutes (without file inclusions parameters) and ~2min (with parameter -> sonar.inclusions=**/TesteBO.java). This time is fair? How can I improve this? Can I execute the analysis for a single file? Thanks..

Comment: You can get the logs from the local analysis by activating the "Console" view in Eclipse, and selecting "SonarQube" stream in the dropdown menu of that view. From what I see from the logs of your standard analysis, it seems you have lots of modules in your project, right?

Comment: Hi Fabrice. Yes, my project has a lot of modules (legacy sux). I Executed the Sonar Analysis from Eclipse Plugin for a single file (using a sonar.inclusions parameter) and the time spent was 1m26sec. The logs can be seem here: (http://pastebin.com/M5LJdhBG). How can improve this analysis for a single file? And a full analysis? I don't undestard the logs from ""Resource not found" and "Load server issues for". Why this is logged?